# PHP/MySQL - inserting JSON data into DB on Bluehost server, empty DB entry

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, bluehost

This is a one-use script to insert the JSON data into my MySQL database on Bluehost. I've used various echo statements inside and outside the loop to make sure the JSON info is parsed correctly and the loop works as expected. Bluehost help files tell me to use SQL statements instead of SQLi or DBO.

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect ("localhost:port", "username", "password");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not reach database: Error Code ' . mysql_error() . "<br>");
    } else {
        echo 'Connected to database. ' . "<br>";
    }
    mysql_select_db ("db_name", $con);

    $jsondata = file_get_contents('BFZ.json');
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    $cards = $data['cards'];

    // loop through the cards array and load each set of variables into the DB
    for($i = 0; $i <= count($cards); $i++) {
        $card_Name = $cards[$i]['name'];
        $card_ManaCost = $cards[$i]['manaCost'];
        $card_CMC = $cards[$i]['cmc'];

        // Clear the variable from its last use
        $card_Colors = "";

        // If the card has no color info, assign the text "Colorless"
        if ($cards[$i]['colors'] == "") {
            $card_Colors = "Colorless";
        // Else if the card has color info, convert the colors array into one long text variable
        } else {
            for($colorIndex = 0; $colorIndex < count($cards[$i]['colors']); $colorIndex++) {
                $card_Colors = $card_Colors . $cards[$i]['colors'][$colorIndex] . " ";
            }
        }

        // various bits to load into the DB
        $card_Type = $cards[$i]['type'];
        $card_Rarity = $cards[$i]['rarity'];
        $card_Text = $cards[$i]['text'];
        $card_Number = $cards[$i]['number'];
        $card_Power = $cards[$i]['power'];
        $card_Toughness = $cards[$i]['toughness'];
        $card_MultID = $cards[$i]['multiverseid'];
        $card_ID = $cards[$i]['id'];

        // insert the data into the cards table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cards (card_ID, card_name, manaCost, cmc, colors, type, rarity, card_text, card_number, power, toughness, multiverseid)
        VALUES ('$card_ID', '$card_Name', '$card_ManaCost', '$card_CMC', '$card_Colors', '$card_Type', '$card_Rarity', '$card_Text', '$card_Number', '$card_Power', '$card_Toughness', '$card_MultID')";
    }
    if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo "Data inserted correctly. <br>";
    }
    $con->close();
?>
```

The last "Data inserted correctly" always triggers, but my DB only has one entry with a 0 stored in cmc, power, toughness, and multiverseid and Colorless in the colors entry. card_ID is my primary key and it's blank.

Either the DB isn't set up properly or I'm missing something in the code. I'd include a screenshot of my DB structure but I'm not sure if that's allowed here. Collation is set to utf8_general_ci and Varchar on the text entries and int or smallint for the numbers. The JSON structure is here: http://mtgjson.com/ .

I didn't know PHP and MySQL until two days ago so forgive me if I'm missing something simple. All other questions I've read don't seem to address this issue.

Comment: 1) Can you post the SQL that gets send to the server (so after PHP inserts the variables)? 2) You might want to check the `mysql_affected_rows()` function (not only if the query is executed ok). 3) Try to use MySQLi instead of MySQL functions, because they are deprecated

Comment: I'm not sure how to do point 1 but I can definitely look into point 2. Point 3, well, I'm not sure the DB or Bluehost allows it but I can try.

Comment: You can `echo $sql;` after you define it

Comment: I just found out the data includes a backslash. I'm not sure how to deal with it, but I think this is the issue I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mysql_query` is outside the for-loop, thats why it only is executed once. It should be

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($cards); $i++) {
    //
    //...
    // insert the data into the cards table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cards (card_ID, card_name, manaCost, cmc, colors, type, rarity, card_text, card_number, power, toughness, multiverseid)        VALUES ('$card_ID', '$card_Name', '$card_ManaCost', '$card_CMC', '$card_Colors', '$card_Type', '$card_Rarity', '$card_Text', '$card_Number', '$card_Power', '$card_Toughness', '$card_MultID')";

    //----> HERE instead
    if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
       die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
       echo "Data inserted correctly. <br>";
    }
}
```

---

```
$card_Type = mysql_real_escape_string($cards[$i]['type']);
$card_Rarity = mysql_real_escape_string($cards[$i]['rarity']);
```

etc

Comment: This gave me a useful error message. I wonder if the content itself is messing this up?

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'graveyards. If you do, put three 1/1 colorless Eldrazi Scion creature tokens ont' at line 2

Comment: There's a / in the file information! Now I have to figure out how to deal with that. If you happen to know of a quick fix, please let me know. Otherwise I'm off to google.

Comment: @KrisHanson, yes - use `mysql_real_escape_string()` - in fact, you should always do that when you are using `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: I just realized it's a forward slash instead of a backslash. Sorry for the mistake.

I want to keep the slash in the data, so I might have to do some PHP regex replacement function?

Comment: @KrisHanson, no - use `mysql_real_escape_string()` anyway.

Comment: @KrisHanson - great you got it to work! Thank you for accepting the answer.